# Currying in_array() in PHP

Tags: php, functional-programming, currying, partial-application

Don't necessarily have a problem with how PHP does this or anything, more just a question out of curiosity. I am familiar with functional programming but am by no means an expert. I am writing functions currently and although I have no requirement for them to be functional, that may change in the future. So best to be prepared I say.

My question is, how would you curry a function like `in_array`?

From what I understand we have two parameters, `needle` and `haystack`.

Both seem to be required when the function is called.

We must know the array we are searching at the start of the function, and we must also know what we are searching for.

To me it seems hard to force any partial application or currying solution whereby we might know one or the other at a later point.

I suppose you could have a non-generic function whereby you specify the `needle` within the function. I did see something about spattering in Google. How would you handle this if asked to rewrite the function and curry it? I know I specified PHP but I suppose any language is really fine as long as the specs are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's relatively straightforward in PHP - almost the same as in any other language that treats functions as values. [**For example**](https://eval.in/954733):

```
function create_search_by_array($arr) {
  return function($needle) use ($arr) {
    return in_array($needle, $arr);
  };
}

$search_in_1_to_10 = create_search_by_array(range(1, 10));
var_dump($search_in_1_to_10(1)); // true
var_dump($search_in_1_to_10(10)); // true
var_dump($search_in_1_to_10(11)); // false
```

The only caveat here is `use ($arr)` construct: without it, the inner function won't be able to see the corresponding variable from an outer scope.

Comment: `return function ($needle)` would literally just return our $needle?

Comment: It returns a function taking a single argument. Have you studied how currying (and partial application) works in general?

Comment: Yes but not in extreme depth. As a solution this is perfect and correct from what I can see. More just as an aside I'm curious as to whether this if functionally the same. On a technical level I also have a question, how did the `$needle` get assigned? I would have thought `$search_in_1_to_10(1))` would have assigned `$arr=1`